# Saving Current Progress or State

Tags: c#

I'm not sure how to solve a problem I have but if my application is scraping Google keywords for say 1,000 webpages, if I cancel the task, or an exception is thrown, what's the best approach for saving how far the task has got, so when it continues it resumes from it's current position.

Do I serialize an object that contains properties with the current status? I've never had to deal with this and unsure of what to actually search for.

Comment: I will store the state to a file when there is exception or cancel to continue from point where it stopped.

Comment: By state what do you mean? A serialized object?

Comment: Yep, I mean current pointer of where it stopped let's say index of a list it was processing, etc

Comment: Could you include this into an answer? So if I created an object that basically just has properties of current state of the task (not Threading Task ... the task the application is doing) then update that object each cycle. On pause, save it. Something like that would be good. Not sure if there are any patterns out there for doing this as most applications do this anyway.

Comment: Could you explain how your program works, because I'm not sure storing the state could solve the problem.

Comment: @JamesJeffery I added my suggestion as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I convert my comment to answer as requested to do.

I'll suggest you to save the state of the task to a file. By `State` I mean the current status of the work your program is doing.

For example, If your application's task is to parse `n` number of files. It encountered an exception in middle of it, let's say file index `45`. Save in a temporary file that you were in `45` so when application runs again you query the temporary file to see whether any task pending, If yes then continue from that point.

Even me too don't know any programming pattern says this approach, I just suggested my idea.

Answer (score 0):

Like database do, use a hard disk:

- Plan your future task in a file
- Each time that you finish a task, append some text (task id o whatever)

You have to deal with some concurrency, but I think that you can deal with it

Use XML is perhaps more advanced to save your plan of work, but after that is more simple to record a file with id's of finished tasks.